# Fatal Error Call To a member Function query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fatal-error

I've seen some of the previous posts on here but they really don't explain what it is I'm looking for.  maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

All I'm doing is a simple select statement that works on some other pages but not this one.

at the top of my page, I have the connection to my db: `include 'myDBconnection.php';` just like any other page that uses it.

I'm using these to tell me what errors I have:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and they are returning this:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/mydomainname.com/httpdocs/somedirectory/index.php on line 16"

So, this is my simple select statement that I'm trying to just display on the page:

```
<?php
//just a simple select statement
if($row = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ErrorCodeTable WHERE ErrorCodeID = 100"))//this is line 16 in my code
{
    $eCodeId = $row['ErrorCodeID'];
    $eCode = $row['ErrorCode'];

    echo $eCodeId." = ".$eCode;
}
?>
```

So, I'm stumped.  Why is it telling me that?

Just for clarity's sake, this is my DB connection and I'm reading from an INI file.

```
function getConnected()
{
    $file = "../myConnection.ini";
    if (!$settings = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE)) throw new exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');

    $host = $settings['connection']['default_host'];
    $user = $settings['connection']['default_user'];
    $paass = $settings['connection']['default_pw'];
    $dbName = $settings['connection']['default_db'];

    $con = 'mysqli_connect("'.$host.'", "'.$user.'", "'.$paass.'", "'.$dbName.'")'; 
    return $con;
}   

//MYSQLI CONNECTION
$con = getConnected();
//CONNECTION CHECK
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}
```

So, why do I get the "Fatal Error" message?  Did I overlook or forget something in my query?
Be gentle. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the below statement

```
$con = 'mysqli_connect("'.$host.'", "'.$user.'", "'.$paass.'", "'.$dbName.'")';
       ^                                                                     ^
```

By enclosing it in single quotes , your `$con` behaves like a string instead of a connection resource. The `mysqli_connect` function will never be executed.

Simply rewrite it like..

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$paass,$dbName);
```

Comment: The problem with that is it's "returning" a string of characters that will be called in the connection below it.  I thought that if I removed it, it would bomb out... am I wrong?

Comment: ohhhhh.  I see... Hang on.

Comment: Just do like this. `$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$paass,$dbName);` You dont need all those quotes around your variables

Comment: Well, now I get this:
"Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /var/www/vhosts/mydomainname.com/httpdocs/somedirectory/index.php on line 18"

Comment: Actually, i did.  But I think I know what that means.  Hang on.

Comment: OK! I figured that last part out.  I wasn't able to use the mysqli_result as an array in my query - so I added another line to it and was able to display the record.  Thank you for your help, @Shankar Damodaran